# Speech API that works both on Windows Phone and Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, speech-recognition

I'm trying to write an app that will work on the windows phone and windows 8.1.

The part that I am running into is the speech recognition.  I can't find a single API that is shared between phone and 8.1.

I have tried Windows.Phone.Speech, but it only works on the phone.  And I have tried Bing.Speech, but it only works on 8.1, and not the phone.  I need one that works on both.

Does Google have an API like this by any chance?

Comment: Overall, questions to find API are not recommended here on stackoverflow. There is no issue to use different APIs on phone and desktop since other sets of APIs are also different. Its easier than to adopt your application for 3rd-part unsupported API like the one from Google. For example CMUSphinx works both on the phone and desktop, however, you will have much more troubles using it than the official Windows.Phone.Speech API.

Comment: I didn't know that.  Thanks for the Stack Exchange tip.  And thanks again for the advice on the problem.  I'll probably just end up doing that.